# Query to fetch the similar products purchased by customer in SQL Server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-mining, data-analysis

Example :

```
  C NAME   PRODUCT      DATE OF PURCHASE 
    **JOHN   MILK        12/17/2015** 
    **JOHN   BREAD       12/17/2015** 
    John     soap        12/17/2015 
   **John    milk        03/21/2016** 
   **John    bread       03/21/2016**
     John    laptop      03/21/2016
     John    pen         07/30/2015
     John    Refils       07/30/2015
     John    Pen         08/05/2016
     John    Refils       08/05/2016
```

By above example we can say, Mr. John always purchase "MILK" & "BREAD" (Mean, when ever he purchases Milk he buy Bread similarly Pen & Refils )

Can anyone send me the query for the above example?

Comment: Can you share your query

Comment: I'ts not clear to me if the example contains sample data or needed result; based on this, can you please add the missing one ( starting data or needed result)?

Comment: In your example Mr John aways purchase Pen & Refils too

Answer (score 0):

If seems that you want to perform some kind of top basket analysis on your data. If that is the case then you can use the following DBMS_FREQUENT_ITEMSET package.

Here are some good links on the same.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_frqist.htm
https://technology.amis.nl/2004/10/16/hidden-plsql-gem-in-10g-dbms_frequent_itemset-for-plsql-based-data-mining/

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to obtain the result, returning the products grouped per couples:

```
SELECT UPPER(t1.c_name), UPPER(t1.product), UPPER(t2.product), COUNT(*)
FROM products t1, products t2
WHERE UPPER(t1.c_name)  = UPPER(t2.c_name)
  AND t1.dt_purchase    = t2.dt_purchase
  AND UPPER(t1.product) < UPPER(t2.product)
GROUP BY UPPER(t1.c_name), UPPER(t1.product), UPPER(t2.product)
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM products t3 
    WHERE UPPER(t3.c_name)  = UPPER(t1.c_name) 
      AND UPPER(t3.product) = UPPER(t1.product) 
) AND COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM products t3 
    WHERE UPPER(t3.c_name)  = UPPER(t1.c_name) 
      AND UPPER(t3.product) = UPPER(t2.product) 
);
```

The query joins the table with itself searching couples of product buyed togheter in all purchasing dates present in table.

This returns following result:

```
JOHN    BREAD   MILK
JOHN    PEN     REFILS
```

Comment: Hi I forgot to handle the char case and the count of records. I corrected the answer. Sorry for the error

Answer (score -1):

This is one (ugly, but working) way to achieve this -

```
select C_Name, product 
from products p1
where date_of_purchase = (select min(date_of_purchase) 
                                                   from products p2                   
                                                   where p1.C_Name = p2.C_Name)
and product not in (select product
                                   from products p3
                                   where p1.C_Name = p3.C_Name
                                   and date_of_purchase <> (select min(date_of_purchase)
                                                                                    from products p4
                                                                                    where p3.C_Name = p4.C_Name))
```

Comment: I tried your query but the result I got is 'John soap'